# Is Outlook .ost file as good as a back-up file?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, imap, email-client

I am using Microsoft Outlook to view gmail emails using IMAP protocol. I notice a .ost file is generated. Is this .ost file as good as a back-up file for my emails? Suppose my gmail account got hacked and I lose access to gmail. Can I use this .ost file to restore all my past emails?

I am using outlook 2013.

Comment: "this .ost file as good as a back-up file for my emails?" - No

Comment: May I ask why since I can use outlook to browse the emails offline?

Comment: Because a OST doesn't contain the actual email but just a cache of the server.  You asked if it was a backup, if you want a backup, create a local .PST archive and copy the emails to it

Comment: If somebody deletes a mail on the Server it will get deleted from your OST file on the next Synchronisation as well, that's not really what you want. (You need to go back to older OST files and make sure you are offline tomrecover such a mail).

Comment: The question "Is X good enough to use as a backup?" should always be replaced with "How do I test X as backup before it's needed?"  Always try it before you need it.  My experience of OST files is that they are not useful as backups.  You must instead make a PST file or use another backup solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OST files are always copies of items that are saved on a mail server, which cannot be used as backup.

As Ramhound suggested, you can create a local .PST and copy the emails to it. Or setup a rule to move a copy of the message you received(or certain type of emails you want to backup) to the PST file.

Introduction to Outlook Data files: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Outlook-Data-Files-pst-and-ost-6d4197ec-1304-4b81-a17d-66d4eef30b78